# Cannot run systemback: Unsafe X Window authorization

Tags: sudo, systemback

When running `systemback`  with non-root user, I get the following message:

[image]

and when running  `sudo systemback`, I get

```
$ sudo systemback
Unsafe X Window authorization!
Please do not use 'sudo' command.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because sudo isn't safe for graphical applications. Please use gksu, or use Systemback internal solution. So Systemback icon, or in terminal:

```
 /usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart systemback

or

/usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart systemback gtk+
```

you can find systemback maintainer by clicking [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/systemback/+question/257019)